# Instagram API start returning loading page after some calls

Tags: python, api, python-requests, instagram, aiohttp

I am using the code below to get account information of one thousand instagram accounts using asycnio. In the initial requests the output is correct but after 10-20 calls, instagram starts returning loading page's HTML code. What could I be doing wrong here ? Below is the python code.

```
import random
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import urllib.request
import  aiohttp
async def fetch(url, session,sem):
    print("------")
    print(url)
    async with session.get(url = url) as response:
        print(await response.text())
        await  response.text()
        # exit()
        if response.status == 200:
            await sem.acquire()
            fname = url[22:]
            fname = fname.split('/')
            fname = fname[0] + '.txt'
            f = open(fname , 'w')
            f.write(str(await response.text()))
            sem.release()

        # return (await response.text())


async def run(url_list):
    tasks = []

    # create instance of Semaphore
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(2)
    # Create client session that will ensure we dont open new connection
    # per each request.
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for url in url_list:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(url, session,sem))
            tasks.append(task)
        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await responses


# making the url list here
url_list = []
file = open('url.txt', 'r')
for url in file:
    url_list.append(url)

print(url_list)
import time
old = time.time()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(url_list))
loop.run_until_complete(future)

print(time.time() - old)
```

Here are some of the URL's from url.txt file

```
https://instagram.com/johanna_kre/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/channie_f/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/lilakuh68/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/nataliacallisto/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/edbastian/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/sylvana.h/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/munich_bombon/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/younotus/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/meet.herbert/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/inaaogo/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/dennisaogo/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/mrslight__/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/reneturrek/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/_eeasyyy/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/sentinobln/?__a=1
https://instagram.com/eri.ka_g/?__a=1
```

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Your semaphore is not limiting the requests as you want it to; you should acquire it before making the request, not before processing the content.

With your current implementation you are making 100 concurrent requests (aiohttp's client default limit) but only process the responses two at a time (however at this point from the server's perspective the requests are already processed).

Use:

```py
async def fetch(url, session,sem):
    print("------")
    print(url)
    await sem.acquire()
    async with session.get(url = url) as response:
        print(await response.text())
        await  response.text()
        ...
    sem.release()
    ...
```

Comment: I tried this, same result. However if I use proxy in the session.get() like                          ``` proxy = 'http://bde366540b6b439f9b973162e0bc1c5a:@proxy.crawlera.com:8010'
    async with session.get(url = url, headers=headers , proxy=proxy,verify_ssl=False) as response:```   It start working correctly

Comment: Perhaps your IP was blocked from previous tests that did not limit the number of concurrent requests.